# Cloud Function for changing the value of a field inside a document after a time lapse?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have Firebase documents, each with the following fields:

Eta as a String value pointing to 5 minutes.

Status as a String value pointing to 'In progress'.

I would like to make a Cloud Function such that 5 minutes after the document is created, the Status field inside the document is changed from 'In progress' to 'Delivered'. What should I write to achieve this?

Comment: hey @Rinor, Hopefully, this article will give you a direction on how to implement it. https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/firebase-cloud-functions-and-cloud-tasks/